# Unity : orthographic camera and shadow

Tags: unity, camera, lighting, shadows

When using an Orthographic Camera, the shadows appear to be of poor quality.

How can I display smooth shadows?[image]

Comment: Maybe a dumb suggestion, but have you tried to put your camera closer to the plane ? Your camera should see the same, but since shadows quality is determined according to the camera's position, you may have better results.

Comment: @Hellium isn't the definition of an orthographic camera that sizes *don't* change with distance?

Comment: The sizes wont change indeed. But the quality of the shadows is based on the camera distance from the shadows so **maybe**, by reducing the distance, the quality of the shadows will increase.

Comment: What's your camera's farplane set to? In the past I've gotten good results by tightly bracketing my scene with the near and far planes, so Unity knows to concentrate the available shadow map detail on the depth range I'm actually using.